# In PHP, what means this error : Warning: ZipArchive::close(): Read error: Bad file descriptor in (...)?

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

I have a PHP script to make a zip with 2 functions :

1. dirToArray : to get all files/empty_folders in an array
2. create_zip : to call dirToArray() and make the zipArchive

I got a weird warning which actually makes a real error because my zip archive is not built.

**Warning result**

> Warning: ZipArchive::close(): Read error: Bad file descriptor in path/to/file.php on line x

Someone can explain me what means : "Bad file descriptor" ?

This is the code :

**dirToArray**

```
/* to copy all file/folder names from a directory into an array*/
function dirToArray($dir_path) {
    $result = array();
    $path = realpath($dir_path);
    $objects = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path), \RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
    foreach($objects as $name => $object) {
        if( $object->getFilename() !== "." && $object->getFilename() !== "..") {
            $result[] = $object;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

**create_zip**

```
/* creates a compressed zip file */
function create_zip($productPath = '', $dirName = '', $overwrite = false) {
    $fullProductPath = $productPath.$dirName;
    $a_filesFolders = dirToArray( $fullProductPath );
    var_dump($a_filesFolders);
    //if the zip file already exists and overwrite is false, return false
    $zip = new \ZipArchive();
    $zipProductPath =  $fullProductPath.'.zip';
    if($zip->open( $zipProductPath ) && !$overwrite){
        $GLOBALS["errors"][] = "The directory {$zipProductPath} already exists and cannot be removed.";
    }

    //if files were passed in...
    if(is_array($a_filesFolders) && count($a_filesFolders)){
        $opened = $zip->open( $zipProductPath, \ZipArchive::CREATE | \ZipArchive::OVERWRITE );
        if( $opened !== true ){
            $GLOBALS["errors"][] = "Impossible to open {$zipProductPath} to edit it.";
        }

        //cycle through each file
        foreach($a_filesFolders as $object) {
            //make sure the file exists
            $fileName = $object -> getFilename();
            $pathName = $object -> getPathname();
            if(file_exists($pathName)) {
                $pos = strpos($zipProductPath , "/tmp/") + 5;
                $fileDestination = substr($pathName, $pos);
                echo $pathName.'<br/>';
                echo $fileDestination.'<br/>';
                $zip->addFile($pathName,$fileDestination);
            }
            else if(is_dir( $pathName )){
                $pos = strpos($zipProductPath , "/tmp/") + 5;
                $fileDestination = substr($pathName, $pos);
                $zip->addEmptyDir($fileDestination);
            }else{
                $GLOBALS["errors"][] = "the file ".$fileName." does not exist !";
            }
        }

        //close the zip -- done!
        $zip->close();
        //check to make sure the file exists
        return file_exists($zipProductPath);
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: My guess is, call to `open()` fails and then you try to close descriptor, that doesn't exist as it hasn't been opened

Comment: I checked with : if( $opened !== true ){
            $GLOBALS["errors"][] = "Impossible to open {$zipProductPath} to edit it.";
        }

Comment: Yeah, but it doesn't stop execution of the script

Comment: I did tests to check these cases, I add return false;... the zip is opened.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem... I was confused by the file_exists() function which detect if directories exist as well... so the script added folders as files and made a bug.

**create_zip (patched)**

```
/* creates a compressed zip file */
function create_zip($productPath = '', $dirName = '', $overwrite = false) {
    $fullProductPath = $productPath.$dirName;
    $a_filesFolders = dirToArray( $fullProductPath );
    var_dump($a_filesFolders);
    //if the zip file already exists and overwrite is false, return false
    $zip = new \ZipArchive();
    $zipProductPath =  $fullProductPath.'.zip';

    if($zip->open( $zipProductPath ) && !$overwrite){
        $GLOBALS["errors"][] = "The directory {$zipProductPath} already exists and cannot be removed.";
        return false;
    }
    //if files were passed in...
    if(is_array($a_filesFolders) && count($a_filesFolders)){
         $opened = $zip->open( $zipProductPath, \ZipArchive::CREATE | \ZipArchive::OVERWRITE );
        if( $opened !== true ){
            $GLOBALS["errors"][] = "Impossible to open {$zipProductPath} to edit it.";
            return false;
        }else{
            //cycle through each file
            foreach($a_filesFolders as $object) {
                //make sure the file exists
                $fileName = $object -> getFilename();
                $pathName = $object -> getPathname();
                if(is_dir( $pathName )){ /*<-- I put on first position*/
                    $pos = strpos($zipProductPath , "/tmp/") + 5;
                    $fileDestination = substr($pathName, $pos);
                    $zip->addEmptyDir($fileDestination);
                }else if(file_exists($pathName)) {
                    $pos = strpos($zipProductPath , "/tmp/") + 5;
                    $fileDestination = substr($pathName, $pos);
                    $zip->addFile($pathName,$fileDestination);
                }
                else{
                    $GLOBALS["errors"][] = "the file ".$fileName." does not exist !";
                }
            }

            //close the zip -- done!
            $zip->close();
            //check to make sure the file exists
            return file_exists($zipProductPath);
        }
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```